# groovy emoji show up as strange square

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm using jenkins dsl jobs to process a job, however, my emoji shows up in the job configure script section as a square like

```
String a = ''
```

my groovy job

```
pipelineJob("title") {
    description("description")
    definition {
        cps {
            script('''
            String a = ''
            ''')
    }
}
```

anyone knows how to fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: Not all fonts and editors does support emoji

Comment: but when I directly copy my script part of the code into script section in configure, it does show properly.

Comment: What encoding is the jenkins server running on?

Comment: I have the same problem: It seems groovy/Java or some interface between them an Jenkins have problems with Unicode code points > 16bit. Haven't figured out how to fix this yet.